# Typeconverter for list of objects in Floor ORM

Tags: flutter, sqflite, typeconverter, floor

Is there any way to use typeconverter for list of objects in floor database, like we have in room database for android.

For example i have entity class which has field list of objects;

```
@Entity(tableName: "example")
class Example {
  @PrimaryKey()
  String id;
  ...
  List<AnotherObject> objects;

}
```

If floor doesn't support typeconverters which flutter ORM would you recommend to use?

Answer (score 1):

floor handles it in the best way, I mean you are free to develop your code for converting all types of data to a data type that is supported by floor.

You can use something like this:

```
class ListSubCategoryFinanceConverter
    extends TypeConverter<List<SubCategoryFinance>, String> {
  @override
  List<SubCategoryFinance> decode(String databaseValue) {
    final jsonFile = json.decode(databaseValue);
    List<SubCategoryFinance> finances = [];
    finances = List.from(jsonFile['subCats'])
        .map((e) => SubCategoryFinance.fromMap(jsonDecode(e)))
        .toList();

    return finances;
  }

  @override
  String encode(List<SubCategoryFinance> value) {
    final data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data.addAll({'subCats': value});
    return json.encode(data);
  }
}
```